# How can I conclude If $b>0$, then $a^2<b$ if and only if $-\sqrt{b} < a$ and $a < \sqrt{b}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to prove the following:

If $b>0$, then $a^2<b$ if and only if $-\sqrt{b} < a$ and $a < \sqrt{b}$

To do so, take:

$a^2-b$= ($a+\sqrt{b} $)($a-\sqrt{b} $)

From where

($a+\sqrt{b} $)($a-\sqrt{b} $)$<0$

This implies

($a+\sqrt{b} $)$<0$ and ($a-\sqrt{b} $)$>0$  or  ($a+\sqrt{b} $)$>0$ and ($a-\sqrt{b} $)$<0$

If I take ($a+\sqrt{b} $)$>0$ and ($a-\sqrt{b} $)$<0$ I get to what I want to test.
But my question is how can I make such a choice if the other option is also correct. How can I conclude the demonstration?

Thanks

Comment: $a^2<b\iff \sqrt a^2<\sqrt b\iff |a|<\sqrt b\iff -\sqrt b<a<\sqrt b$...

Comment: You are right, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is correct.  The first option is impossible: it would imply that $a < -\sqrt{b}$ and also $a > \sqrt{b}$, and that can't happen.  So the only way the statement can be true is if the second option is true, and as you correctly show, this happens if and only if $-\sqrt{b} < a < \sqrt{b}$.